# Unity3d code size differs from UI size

Tags: unity-game-engine

[I got a square in Unity with a size of 500x500(slightly transparent).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBuGO.png)

Additionally, I want to take a snapshot of this area. Therefore, I created the following code for taking a picture(the area has got a size of 500x500).

```
public class CameraShot : MonoBehaviour{

private int width = 500; 
private int height = 500;
private string saveFolder = "/picture";
private string saveType = ".png";

public void MakePicture()
{
    var texture = SetClipping();
    EncodeAndSafe(texture);        
}

private Texture2D SetClipping()
{
    int x = (Screen.width - width) / 2;
    int y = (Screen.height - height) / 2;

    Debug.Log("[AR_Recognition] CameraShot: " + Screen.dpi);

    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    Rect rect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

    tex.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    return tex;
}

private void EncodeAndSafe(Texture2D texture)
{
    int count = 1;
    var bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
    Destroy(texture);

    string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + saveFolder;

    while (true) {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(savePath))
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(savePath+count+saveType, bytes);
            Debug.Log("[AR_Recognition] CameraShot: " + savePath + saveType);
            break;
        } 
    }       
}
```

Now I got the following issue:

[The picture taken is not matching the 500x500 square but I cannot figure out why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ltz.png)

Ty

EDIT: [The Canvas information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyb0E.png)

Comment: for the UI image what is the reference resolution for the canvas?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Not sure how you got the 2nd picture... but if you are using OnGUI, then OnGUI will draw a 500x500 pixel box regardless of your screen size, your second image is on a Canvas with a Canvas Scaler, this means all children objects will scale depending on your resolution. The difference here is you are saying give me a box area that is 500x500 pixels regardless of what the screen resolution is. I would attempt it like this in your script `int width = (Screen.width / (float)2550) * 500;` and `int height = (Screen.height / (float) 1440) * 500;`  Since that is how your canvas is scaling that area.

Comment: I am dividing the width and height by 2550 and 1440 (To match similarly what is going on with the canvas scaler) in order to get the % of difference and then scaling the 500x500 area by those values...  give that a try and let me know if it works out...

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked out perfectly!